# Simplifying deployment configs for SpringMVC project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deployment, spring-security

We've multi module SpringMVC project, each having separate applicationContext.xml,  currently we have to edit the applicationContext.xml files for every module before we deploy. It's painful and error prone. Is there a way to have only one property file that all other will contexts look at. Then we only have to edit one property file before we build and deploy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every applicationContext.xml contains vommon database properties which changes for production, testing and development environment. So changing each XML file for each environment is hectic. So, if there is single properties file which other XML files could read from, would be great.

Comment: It sounds like based on your response to my answer, that the above comment regarding environments is not actually the issue. Could you update the question with more information about your actual code layout and what exactly you're attempting to share between modules?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using Spring's Profile support, which allows you to specify separate properties files per environment. You can pass the application an environment property `spring.profiles.active` and set it to say, "dev", "test", or "prod".

If you're using Spring Boot it can then automatically pick up distinct configuration per environment, `application.dev.properties` or `application.prod.properties` which will overwrite the standard `application.properties` with environment specific configuration.

If not using Spring Boot you would just have configure your Properties Sources per profile.

This is most definitely the preferred approach to changing configuration files at build or deploy time.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment

Comment: It's not about environment specific. It's about having single property file which can be used by multiple project modules applicationContext.xml files. So you just change one file not all  applicationContext.xml.